# ruby sinatra remote connection

Tags: ruby, apache, sinatra

I'm trying to get hello world working remotely in sinatra:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "hello world"
end
```

locally it works fine:

```
curl localhost:4567
hello world
```

but when I try to access it remotely, I get a 404 error.
The server is visible; I have other web applications running just fine (but not on nonstandard ports). this is a near-stock ubuntu install so there aren't any iptables rules that would block access to port 4567. Is there something I'm missing? I've had difficulty googling this.

Comment: What is the URL you're using when you try to access your Sinatra app remotely?

Comment: Are you using Passenger to serve your Sinatra app? Is the configuration correct there?

Comment: the url I'm using is <ip address>:4567. I'm not using passenger, I'm using sinatra out of box, so I think thats Rack on Mongrel

Comment: How do you launch the server? What command do you run?

Comment: When Sinatra starts, it tells you what address and port to use. You should also be able to use 127.0.0.1, or 0:0:0:0.

Comment: How is your remote machine serving up the Sinatra app? If you're not running Passenger, Sinatra will start on localhost, which is inaccessible from outside.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume this is not firewall issue. Add bind `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` something like below

```
#app.rb
require 'sinatra'
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
get "/" do
    "Working"
end
```

to run this

```
ruby app.rb
```